# Can you download data from satellites which are no longer in use?

Tags: education, spain, radio

I thought about doing a small educational project to test my skills in communication systems engineering and I saw plenty of videos from people **accessing and downloading** data from satellites which are **no longer in use**.

The only regulations I know are those regulating *antenna size* and the permission to *transmit data at a radio frequency* (to not interfere with other objects).

But, **Is there any law inside or outside USA where it is illegal to do that?**
that I must know before doing anything illegal without knowledge of it?

I've searched on the internet and found nothing.

I live in Spain.

Comment: Satellites owned/managed by private companies, or by governments?

Comment: I would like to know for both of them.

Comment: In addition to the radio aspects, there may be computer law involved if you are doing more than passively listening for data that is being sent. If you are sending a request in order to tell the satellite to start sending data that opens new aspects to the question.

Comment: To be direct and to the point; and also to state the obvious: What are your intended plans on communication (or listening) with the sattelite? To what end are you wanting to interact with the satellite? What type of communication will you be interacting with the satellite? And which sattelite do you plan on communicating with? If you can provide the following details; perhaps this will provide the proper context to answer the question with relevancy and accuracy.

Comment: I would like to be able to download weather data from an old satellite, for example. Sorry for the delay in answer i had exams.